# How can we prove that $a!\times b! \mid (a+b)!$

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility

For natural number $a,b$, how can I see the fact that $a!\times b! \mid (a+b)!$ ?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Binomial coefficients!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknow Thanks I have seen what coefficient is it.

Comment: Argue that the product of $b$ consecutive integers is a multiple of $b!$. Then the above will be clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know binomial coefficients are integers, then $\binom{a+b}{a}=\dfrac{(a+b)!}{a!b!}$.